# Handling multiple rewrite conditions (one for live and one for development server)

Tags: apache, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a drupal 7 site. I have the live site and the development site for staging module updates. The live site has an associated domain name, whereas my dev site uses the ip address:port for access. Something like this: www.customersite.com for live and 10.0.1.10:10091 for dev.

In the Drupal 7 .htaccess file is code one can uncomment so that non-www requests are appended with "www." However, I don't want this behavior when running on the IP site. How can I create a the correct rewrite condition for this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10.0.1.10\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use different `.htaccess` for live, test, stage, development and whatever may occur. On the corresponding system just copy the right one

```
cp .htaccess-live .htaccess
```

This will also keep things more simple.

Comment: Thanks @kingcrunch. I use commenting in this way now. I was hoping for something so that I didn't have to remember to make the change when I push updates to the live site.

Comment: Write a script, that gets executed during the deploy-process.

Answer (score 0):

@KingCrunch. Here's a totally different method that works pretty well for me, and I just have to copy/paste my whole source folder without touching anything, and it works pretty well.

Use two different vhosts: one for dev, and one for prod. Two different files.

First one for the prod:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/web/htdocs/mydomain/prod"

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Second one for the dev:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/web/htdocs/mydomain/dev"

    ServerName dev.mydomain.com

</VirtualHost>
```

And in my hosts file, they all go to the same IP.
In my Php code, to access database, I do something like:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
  /* usual HTTP page */
  define('HOST', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
else {
  /* command line */
  define('HOST', 'command_line');
}
/* define db access depending on host: */
if (HOST == 'command_line') {
  /* command line */
  define( 'SQL_CNX_NOM_BD', 'mydomain_dev');
}
elseif ((mb_ereg('dev\.',HOST) !== false) ) { 
  define( 'SQL_CNX_NOM_BD', 'mydomain_dev');
}
elseif ((mb_ereg('mydomain',HOST) !== false) ) { 
  define( 'SQL_CNX_NOM_BD', 'mydomain_prod');
}
else {
  throw new Exception("unable to determine db ".
    "with this host: ".HOST);
}
```

Then I just have to copy/paste my whole source folder without touching anything, and it works pretty well.

Comment: Worth to mention, that I highlighted the simplicity.  However, most of your code is application configuration, but the question was about how to differentiate between different hosts in the `.htaccess` and not in PHP. Sidenotes: `*ereg*()` is deprecated, `mb_*()` is useless here, regular expressions are expensive

Comment: Thanks Olivier. However, the live site is a shared site that doesn't expose the vhosts file in any helpful way. Drush excludes the settings.php file, so that's is managed in an excluded way.

Comment: My #1 advice: it's always better to manage everything. I pay $23/month for my own dedicated server with a huge bandwidth. Well err... I'm in France.

Comment: Olivier: heh, if only I could manage my customer's prior vending arrangements. I agree with you, but I wouldn't refuse business if a customer has such a prior arrangement. either.

Comment: Think about that: will it be a good thing *in the long run* to stay in such environment. If it's a "long term" client, maybe you could migrate the whole solution for free (you'll be the winner *in the long run*)